# PDO query with variable and string concatenated as table name

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, concatenation

I have this query

```
$prefix = 'de_';
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $prefix.request_products (created_at, request_id) VALUES (NOW(), :request_id)";
```

Which would be working, but php or PDO (or both) are writing the dot within the query, the table name is `de_request_products` but the query is build as `de_.request_products`.

If I just use a space between $prefix and the string PDO throws an error.

Is there any other possibility of how to concatenate the string and the variable within the query, or is the only way to build it like this:

```
$prefix = 'de_';
$table = 'request_products';
$concat = $prefix.$table;
$sql = INSERT INTO $concat ...
```

Comment: Try `"INSERT INTO ".$prefix."request_products ....` or `"INSERT INTO {$prefix}request_products ....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `${variable}` syntax:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ${prefix}request_products (created_at, request_id) VALUES (NOW(), :request_id)";
```

Answer (score 1):

The manual here: http://php.net/manual/pl/language.types.string.php
says: "Enclose the variable name in curly braces to explicitly specify the end of the name."
So this should make you happy:

```
$prefix = 'de_';
$sql = "INSERT INTO ${prefix}request_products (created_at, request_id) VALUES (NOW(), :request_id)";
```